# How to set primary key in sqlldr ctl file?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-loader

here i have below file

```
load data
infile 'emp.csv'
into table EMPLOYEES
append
fields terminated by ',' 
optionally ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
TENANTID,
EMPLOYEEID,
ISEMPLOYEEACTIVE,
PASSWORD,
EMPLOYEEMANAGERID,
FIRSTNAME,
LASTNAME,
MIDDLENAME,
EMPLOYEEEMAILID,
EMPLOYEEASSISTANTID ,
CATEGORYID,
EMPLOYEENATIONALITY,
BRANCHID ,
GRADEID ,
PASSWORDRESETTOKEN,
PASSWORDRESETCREATEDATE,
ISBRANCHHEAD ,
DEFAULTCOSTCODE ,
GENDER 
)
```

in this file `EMPLOYEEID` is primary key so how to set that column as a primary key...
because every time it required unique and auto generated number

and here my emp.csv file

```
1006,1,0,saasas,1049,LoadData,lol,lol,bhargav121@gmail.com,1049,1125,India,2192,1128,1,1,1,1051,m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In db. 
`create sequence EMPLOYEES_SEQ`

In ctlfile

```
...
TENANTID,
EMPLOYEEID "EMPLOYEES_SEQ.NEXTVAL",
ISEMPLOYEEACTIVE,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also maintain a column with datatype as `NUMBER` and constraint `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`. So that while loading, a unique numeric identifier with incremented value for each row will be inserted defaultly.

Egg:

```
CREATE TABLE members(
    member_id **NUMBER** **GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY**,
    first_name VARCHAR2(50),
    last_name VARCHAR2(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(member_id)
);
```

For skipping fields/columns while loading through sql loader, visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695375/skipping-data-fields-while-loading-delimited-data-using-sqlldr)